# Is urlopen lazily evaluated?

Tags: python

```
# Get the content type of a URL
def get_url_type(url: str) -> str:
  r = urlopen(url)
  header = r.headers
  return header.get_content_type()
```

Would the following only fetch the headers or would it fetch the whole document?

I'm using this to check if it is or not an html page, to avoid downloading (big) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that only the headers and a bit of the body is retrieved in the `urlopen()` call, and the rest is gotten upon the `read()`.

In testing this with something like wireshark, you can see that even if you call `urllib.urlopen('VeryLargeFile')` you still only receive headers and a few packets of body initially.

However, if you only wish to know the size of a page or its content type you can use `requests`:

```
import requests

rh = requests.head(url)
header = rh.headers
content_type = header.get('content-type')

print(content_type)
# text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I've check out urllib source code, it's lazily evaluated.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1169b0b3ca1812b97382ee16a2fad4b0e7506eaf/Lib/http/client.py#L311

Firstly it will only read header.  And it will only read body when you call `read` in the response object

Comment: Thank you. Would passing the result of urlopen to BeautifulSoup trigger .read() ? That's what made me want to check headers first, I use BeautifulSoup to get html's <title> and I had a hunch it was downloading full non-html files sometimes to try to fetch that.

Comment: Yes it is.  Here is relative source code: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L311

Which says that if you pass a file object(which has `read` method), it will call read first

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.google.com'
%timeit -n 25 requests.head(url).headers
%timeit -n 25 requests.request('HEAD', url).headers
%timeit -n 25 requests.get(url).headers
```

Output:

```
185 ms ± 13.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 25 loops each)
171 ms ± 18.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 25 loops each)
242 ms ± 29.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 25 loops each
```

Making a specific 'HEAD' type request seems to be fastest.